# Ruby on Rails: Showing Member's Name Instead of ID in Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, custom-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [making a pretty url via ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747483/making-a-pretty-url-via-ruby)

I have looked around but I can't find an answer.  I am either not asking the right question and/or I am not looking in the right place.

I have the following defined:

```
config/routes.rb
resources :members

members_controller.rb
def show
@member = Member.find(params[:id])
end
```

As of now when showing a member, the URL is http://myapp.tld/members/1.  Let's say the member's name was cooldude.  How hard would it be to show http://myapp.tld/members/cooldude or even http://myapp.tld/cooldude if possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) but if you want to roll a solution of your own, this should get you started:

1. Add a `slug` field to your model
2. Set the `slug` field before saving
3. Override `to_param` in your model to return the `slug` instead of `id`

Setup your model:

```
# member.rb
before_save do
  self.slug = name.parameterize
end

def to_param
  slug
end
```

Change your finder to:

```
# members_controller.rb
def show
  @member = Member.find_by_name!(params[:id])
end
```

Note that `find_by_name!` (see the bang?) will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception rather than returning `nil`. In production, this will automatically show a 404 page.

In your views, you can use `member_path(@member)` which will now return `/members/cool-dude` instead of `/members/1`.

Check out the docs:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base (section on dynamic attribute-based finders)